# Why is my backend not working when the site is online?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, backend

I'm doing a dynamic site in php5.Contents like gallery,news,etc can be added from the backend.It works perfectly in localhost. But when I loaded it online, the dynamic part wasn't working. Php version of my cpanel was 7.2 by default. I changed it to 5.3. Now my front-end is working (dynamic part) but the backend is not working. I'm able to login to the backend using the username and password given in my database. But after logging in, it shows a blank page.

Changing the php version of my cpanel could only fix the frontend but the backend is still not working.

This is the error that I'm getting
[host www.sitename.com] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'admin/config/connection.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/php') in /home/mistrybu/public_html/index.php on line 373\n

[image: Php Version]

Comment: I think it is .htaccess file issue. Check your rule rewrite engine rules. If that is fine, does your site use any php extensions?

Comment: can you provide some error logs?

Comment: lots of reason can be here like database connection, your file path , .htaccess atleast you need to give in your question error log or peace of code where is the issue

Comment: Check Your Cpanel > File Manager > Bankend Folder > Check your error_log FIle if any Code Error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to enable `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` so that what type of error happened.
Problem might be database configuration, misspelled function call, wrong file path, etc.
To fix the problem you should first enable `error_reporting` then find the solution of the error.

Comment: i'm getting this error : [host www.sitename.com] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'admin/config/connection.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/php') in /home/mistrybu/public_html/index.php on line 373\n

Comment: make sure you are providing the right file path to require_once() as parameter.